# Alternative for typing a nextjs page - one line

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have the following

```
type Props = {
  name: string
}

const Home: NextPage<Props>= ({name: string}) => {
```

This work fine but is there an alternative? Can I do it all in one line?

Comment: Put the whole Props between `<>` then?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
const Home: NextPage<{name:string}>= ({name}) => {}
```